# What is the name of the sefer that lists the simanim in shulhan aruch where maran is posek according to kabbalah

Tags: halacha, mysticism-kabbalah

What is the name of the sefer that lists the simanim in shulhan aruch where maran is posek according to kabbalah i.e. like sitting down while putting on tefillin shel yad

Comment: Hi Harry. Why do you think such a sefer exists that you ask for its name?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: @Double AA. There’s a rav I listen to on YouTube who’s mentioned it at least 2 times. But I listen to all his shiurim and I dont know which one is was!